# Laravel hasMany relation in table with rowspan and <tr>

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

**Models**

```
/**
 * Get the author
 */
public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Author');
}

/**
 * Get the author books
 */
public function book()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Book');
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function getAuthorBook(){
  $authors = Author::with('book')->get();
  return view('user.author', compact('authors');
}
```

**view**

```
<table>
    <thead>
       <tr>
         <th class="text-center">Author</th>
         <th class="text-center">book tilte</th>
         <th class="text-center">Description</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
  <tbody>
   @foreach($authors as $auth)
       <tr>
       <td rowspan="{{count($auth->book)+1}}">
           {{$auth->name}}
       </td> 
           <td>
           @foreach($auth->book as $book)
             <tr>
              {{$book->libelle}}
             </tr>
           @endforeach
           <td>

           <td>
           @foreach($auth->book as $book)
           <tr>
              {{$book->description}}
           </tr>
           @endforeach
           <td>
      </tr>
     @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to display the authors with their books, basically the authors in one column and their books in another to represent on different line as in the following picture:
 [table with vertical rowspan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1wqW.png)

Please help me to achieve this dynamic table

Comment: Can you elaborate the ques a bit?

Answer (score 1):

You have to just add condition for the first column to add rowspan & keep everything similar to how you keep for simple row.
Also, I assume that `{{count($auth->book)}}` will add the rowspan. But I am not sure why you added 1 to the count.

```
@foreach($authors as $auth)
    @php ($first = true)
    @foreach($auth->book as $book)
        <tr>
        @if($first == true)
            <td rowspan="{{count($auth->book)}}">
                {{$auth->name}}
            <td>
            @php ($first = false)
        @endif
        </td>
        <td>
            {{$book->libelle}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{$book->description}}
        </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I hope this helps.